# Kitchen hangs during test chef role

Tags: .net, vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, test-kitchen

I have creating some chef cookbooks and all works correctly.
Now I want to use kitchen for testing my recipe and cookbooks.
Kitchen run on Linux centos 7 and I use virtualbox.

If I launch recipe to install ms_dotnet 4.5 on win server 2008 all works correctly.

If I launch the same recipe using kitchen on same platform chef client hangs on this message
**update content in file  (file sizes exceed 10000000 bytes, diff output suppressed)**

If I open virtual box and show the desktop, the directory and the executable of .dotnet 4.5 is present.
And if I try to install the .dotnet 4.5 without kitchen all runs correctly.

How can I resolve my problems?

Thanks you so much

Comment: Please include your kitchen config and logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problems!

I modify my kitchen.yml and insert:

```
  - name: softsolutions/win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm-sp1
    transport:
        name: winrm
        elevated: true
        elevated_username: System
        elevated_password: null
```

Now msdotnet cookbook works correctly.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

This is my kitchen config

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  boot_timeout: 1200
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  require_chef_omnibus: 12.5.1

platforms:
  - name: softsolutions/redhat72
  - name: softsolutions/centos67  
  - name: softsolutions/centos7  
  - name: softsolutions/opensuse113
  - name: softsolutions/win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm
    transport:
        name: winrm
  - name: softsolutions/win-7-professional-amd64-nocm
    transport:
        name: winrm  

suites:
  #Roles for physical machines
  - name: do-base
    run_list:
        - role[do-base]
```

And this is my kitchen log (when try to install dotnet 4.5)

```
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:41.503828 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm:  (up to date)
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:41.504670 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm:   * execute[set_for_current_shell] action run
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:41.505538 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm:     - execute PATH=%PATH%;C:\BuildTools\apache-maven\bin\
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:41.506393 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm: Recipe: ms_dotnet45::default
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:41.507264 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm:   * windows_package[Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5] action install
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:44.344388 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm:     * remote_file[C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache/ms_dotnet-4.5.exe] action create
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:46.292294 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm:       - create new file C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache/ms_dotnet-4.5.exe
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:46.293742 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm:       - update content in file C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache/ms_dotnet-4.5.exe from none to 6c2c58
I, [2017-02-24T15:39:46.295069 #31565]  INFO -- do-developer-softsolutions-win-2008r2-standard-amd64-nocm:       (file sizes exceed 10000000 bytes, diff output suppressed)
```